# What's the second meaning of "blue" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

A Reddit 'Shower thoughts' [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/6hy9cs/if_you_borrow_someones_newly_bought_blue_cheese/):

> If you borrow someone's newly bought blue cheese, you would have something old, something new, something borrowed, and something blue all in one item.
>
> You could go to a wedding with that one item!

I'm guessing there's some pun or other non-obvious meaning behind 'blue' here, likely some contrast to 'borrowed' but I don't think I've ever encountered it in such context. What's so special about 'blue' that it got included here that the post raked up 17,500 upvotes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Reddit poster refers to a British custom, in which a bride is sometimes presented with "Something old, something new, something borrowed, and something blue." These are carried by the bride as good luck charms.

The custom is said to have its origin in a nursery rhyme:

> Something Olde, Something New, Something Borrowed, Something Blue, A Sixpence in your Shoe

Tradition holds that the "Something blue" represents fidelity, purity, and love. "Something old" represents tradition. "Something new" augurs a prosperous future. "Something borrowed" is taken to represent happiness. The "Sixpence in your shoe" is meant to ensure prosperity.

I imagine that the post garnered an extravagent vote total simply because it is a clever play on the wording of the custom and the rhyme.

A more scholarly digression on the custom and the rhyme can be found in [this Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_old)

Comment: But why is the cheese "something old"?  Just because it has to age to become blue-veined cheese?

Comment: @RossPresser Well, blue cheese _is_ aged to a degree. And we should be thankful that the Reddit poster did not endeavor to satisfy the _sixpence in your shoe_ argument; I think we can all agree that blue cheese borne in one's shoe conjures a distinctly odoriferous image.

Comment: To be pedantic, you don't actually answer the question. In fact, you just repeat the exact same words which the OP is asking about, "something blue". You've explained what "something blue" represents and where the saying comes from, but not the intended meaning of "blue". You don't actually state that both uses of the word "blue" are intended to mean the color blue.

Comment: @Makyen The OP is asking about the second blue explicitly.

Comment: It's a very widespread US custom, too. Even the sixpence in the shoe—sometimes a silver dollar or other US coin here, but some brides go so far as to get an antique British sixpence. I wouldn't suggest putting blue cheese in a bridal shoe, though.

Comment: @jaxad0127, Yes, that is what the OP asks about in the question's title. That the inquiry in the question's title is about the meaning of "blue" in "something blue" and that this answer does not actually answer that question was the point I was trying to make. Given that, I'm not sure what you are attempting to communicate with your comment.

Comment: @Makyen Well, the answer does state: _Tradition holds that the "Something blue" represents fidelity, purity, and love._  This seems to me an answer to the question posed in the title. I assume that by "second meaning", the OP connotes the meaning of the word in the originating rhyme. Do you think the OP intends something else? Surely the OP already understands what imparts the color to the veins in blue cheese.

Comment: As @Makyen said, the 'blue' asked about is the colour of the cheese - or rather, the colour of the growth within it, giving it the name 'blue cheese'.  It meets the 'something blue' requirement by being 'blue cheese'

Comment: @Baldrickk I read it the other way around, not asking about the colour of the cheese, but about the old, new, borrowed and blue thingy.

Comment: @MrLister that's how I read it too... the blue cheese satisfies the 'blue' in something blue.  Maybe my comment wasn't too clear in how it started...

Comment: @Baldrickk The question could have been clearer too; if I'm right, "the second meaning of blue" should have been "the meaning of the second blue".

Comment: "The custom is said to have its origin in a nursery rhyme:" - Nursery rhymes often have their origin in something much older than the rhyme - and sometimes the true origin was far from being "suitable for children!"

Comment: @alephzero Aye! Thus my punt to the Wikipedia article, where garters and the evil eye enter the discussion

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing there's some pun or other non-obvious meaning behind 'blue' here

Nope.

The veins in blue cheese are actually blue in color, so that's "something blue".

Cheese has to be aged before being sold or consumed, so it's also "something old".

However, for someone buying the cheese, it's "something new", at least on the day it's bought.

And finally, if someone takes it temporarily and gives it back later, it becomes "something borrowed".

So yeah, it's a clever way to tick off all the boxes for "something old, something new, something borrowed, something blue".